# How do I pull the rubber plug out of this despenser

Tags: substitute-tool, kitchen

Is it possible to pull the plug (white object in the bottle in the image) out with no special tool.
[image: Rubber plug in the despenser]

Comment: Does it have a hole though the centre, or is it airtight in the neck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be able to pull it out with a hook.

You can unbend things like a wire coat hanger, a very large paper clip or a similar object and then bend it into a long hook that fits through the bottle neck.

Try to push the whole hook through the middle opening of the plug, then let one end of the hook wrap around the outside of the plug. You should then be able to pull it through the bottle neck.

---

Another solution that is way more fiddly is to use a string to pull it out.

First you need to bind a weight to the end like a small screw nut. Let the string down into the bottle and put the weight through the opening in the plug. Then gentla shake the bottle around so the string catches the plug and the weight falls back out of the bottle neck. You can then pull on both ends of the string to pull the plug out.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming a plastic bag doesn't count as a "special tool", you could try this approach.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLMH0NrdfNE

In case the video disappears, the short version (pictures are just screen caps from the linked video):

1. Twist the bag and insert it most of the way into the bottle, leaving the top facing out
   [image: jamming plastic bag into bottle]
2. Turn the bottle upside down and gently shake it - the goal is to get the stopper close to the neck of the bottle, nestled inside the plastic bag
   [image: getting the stopper near the neck]
3. Blow into the bag, inflating it around the plug
4. Twist the bag around the plug and pull the bag out, bringing the plug with it

Answer (score 1):

Looks like plug is polyethylene.   Acetone dissolves polyethylene, so get a bottle of nail polish remover (acetone), pour it in and wait till it dissolves enough to let it flow out.

Comment: +1 for thinking outside the box - but I rather assume the OP wants to re-use the stopper afterwards!

Comment: I think you meant to say polystyrene.

Comment: No, the yellow top may be polystyrene, however the plug in the bottle looks like a softer polyethylene which makes a good plug in which to insert the yellow top..   Polyethylene is resistant to most solvents but not acetone.  http://www.cdf1.com/technical%20bulletins/Polyethylene_Chemical_Resistance_Chart.pdf

Comment: I'd have guessed at it being a silicone sort of rubber myself. It looks like the rubber seal on a cordial/alcohol dispenser spout- it should hence have a hole right through and a hook would be a reasonable option